# Timestamp keeps updating in admin

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id_str = models.CharField(verbose_name="Transaction ID", max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date of creation", auto_now_add=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_transaction_id()

    def set_transaction_id(self):
        dt = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.id_str = str(dt.year) + str(dt.month) + str(dt.day).zfill(2) + \
                      str(dt.hour) + str(dt.minute).zfill(2) + str(dt.second).zfill(2)
```

I want to use the the timestamp of point where the model instance is created to assign `id_str`. I can't use model field `created` because `__init__` runs first.
But in the above code, after creating the model instance and `id_str` assigned, when I refresh the admin page, `id_str` also gets refreshed to an updated timestamp. Why does `datetime.now()` refreshes itself in admin?

Comment: Because `__init__` also runs when it loads objects from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `__init__` also runs when it loads objects from the database. Therefore the Django documentation [discourages overriding `__init__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model), since loading objects from the database are impacted as well.

You however do not need to override init. You can simply wrap the value for the `id_str` in a function, and use this as default:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def default_transaction_id():
    return now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

class Transaction(models.Model):
    id_str = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Transaction ID',
        max_length=200,
        default=default_transaction_id
    )
    # …
```